# error compiling a beamer file with pdflatex

Tags: beamer, errors, compiling, dvi

I type the command \pdflatex otticaCIDI.tex and get the following error:
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfmx',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.

If I ignore the warning, I obtain a file with black pages.
Thanks for the answer
Leila

My file preamble is:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx,unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red!90!black}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pict2e,curve2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\beamertemplatetransparentcovereddynamic
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with pdflatex, you should not use the `dvipdfmx` option.

Some other comments: You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer - beamer already loads these packages for you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red!90!black}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pict2e,curve2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\beamertemplatetransparentcovereddynamic

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```